# show that $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\tan x)dx=0$

Tags: integration, contour-integration

show that $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\tan x)dx=0$$

using two ways The first with real analysis and the second with contour integration

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\tan x)dx= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin x)dx-\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\cos x)dx= 0 $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following general formula

$$\tag{1}F(a,b) = \int^{\infty}_0 \frac{x^b}{x^2+a^2}\, \,dx $$

$$F(a,b) = \frac{1}{a^2}\,\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{x^b}{\frac{x^2}{a^2}+1} \, dx$$

Let $\frac{x^2}{a^2} = t$

$$F(a,b) = \frac{a^b}{2|a|} \,\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{t^{\frac{b-1}{2}}}{t+1} \, dt = \frac{a^b \, \pi }{2|a| \sin\left( \pi \frac{b+1}{2}\right)}$$

where I used the beta function .

$$F(a,b)=\frac{a^b \, \pi }{2|a| \sin\left( \pi \frac{b+1}{2}\right)}$$

Differentiate wrt to $b$

$$\frac{\partial F(a,b)}{\partial b} = \frac{a^b \, \pi  \, \ln|a| }{2|a| \sin\left( \pi \frac{b+1}{2}\right)} - \frac{a^b \, \pi^2 }{4|a| } \cot^2 \left(\pi \frac{b+1}{2}\right)$$

$$\frac{\partial F(a,0)}{\partial b}= \int^{\infty}_0 \frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+a^2}\, \,dx=\frac{ \, \pi  \, \ln|a| }{2|a|} $$

In particular

$$\frac{\partial F(1,0)}{\partial b}= \int^{\infty}_0 \frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+1}\, \,dx=0 $$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** For the calculus approach, note that $\tan(\pi/2-x)=\frac{1}{\tan x}$. So split the interval into $0$ to $\pi/4$, and $\pi/4$ to $\pi/2$. For the second half, make the change of variable $x=\pi/2-u$.

When we make the change of variable, we have to wade through a morass of minus signs. One comes  from $dx=-du$; another comes from the fact that the integration bounds will be in the "wrong" order; and a third comes from $\ln(1/t)=-\ln(t)$.

Comment: thanks but is there another way to solve it by contour integration ?and how ?

Comment: I will leave it to others to do that one. The form described in Peter Tamaroff's answer is I think more convenient for that (although the given answer there again is a real variable one).

Answer (score 3):

Using Cameron's (now deleted) comment that the integral is $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{1+x^2}dx$$ split at $x=1$ and use $x\mapsto x^{-1}$.

Comment: @julien Join the chat and you'll know! =D

Answer (score 3):

Going from @PeterTamaroff's integral form,

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{x}}{1+x^2}$$

we may employ a contour integration.  Consider the integral

$$\oint_C dz \frac{\log^2{z}}{1+z^2}$$

where $C$ is a keyhole contour about the positive real axis.  The integral vanishes along the outer and inner circular contours about the origin.  The contour integral is then equal to the integral up and back along the positive real axis.  Recalling that, below the axis, $z=x e^{i 2 \pi}$, we may write the iintegral as

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log^2{x}-(\log{x}+i 2 \pi)^2}{1+x^2} = -i 4 \pi \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{x}}{1+x^2} +4 \pi^2 \int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$

This integral is equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues at the poles $z=\pm i $, or $z_1 = e^{i \pi/2}$ and $z_2=e^{i 3 \pi/2}$:

$$i 2 \pi \left ( \frac{-\pi^2/4}{2 i} + \frac{-9 \pi^2/4}{-2 i}\right )= 2 \pi^3$$

Knowing that

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

we have

$$-i 4 \pi \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{x}}{1+x^2} +2 \pi^3 =2 \pi^3$$

or

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{x}}{1+x^2} = 0$$

Comment: http://www.mathhelpboards.com/f28/logarithm-integral-5273/#post24061 , we have a general approach to solve by contours .Of course for $a=1$ we have $I = 0 $

Answer (score 2):

As $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx,$

$$I=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\ln(\tan x) dx=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\ln\left(\tan \left(\frac\pi2+0-x\right)\right) dx=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\ln(\cot x) dx$$
$$=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\ln (\tan x)^{-1} dx=-\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\ln(\tan x) dx=-I$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\color{#66f}{\Large\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\tan\left(x\right)\right)\,{\rm d}x}
& = &
\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\ln\left(\tan\left(x + {\pi \over 4}\right)\right)\,{\rm d}x
\\&=&
\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\ \underbrace{\quad%
\ln\left(1 + \tan\left(x\right) \over 1 - \tan\left(x\right)\right)\quad}
_{\displaystyle{\mbox{Odd function of}\ x}}\ {\rm d}x = \color{#66f}{\Large 0}
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\log\tan x= \log\sin x-\log\cos x$$
and since sine and cosine are symmetric on $(0,\pi/2)$, with respect to the line $x=\pi/4$, their integrals are equal. That is
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\sin x dx = \int_0^{\pi/2}\log\cos x dx$$

Answer (score 0):

$$Let$$
$$Tanx-> x$$
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{lnx}{1+x^{2}}dx$$$$substitution x=\frac{1}{x}$$$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{-lnx}{1+x^{2}}dx\\I+I=0$$$$I=0$$